# Cómo obtener el valor de un archivo JSON con PHP

Tags: php, json

quiero saber como obtener el valor de una propiedad que se encuentra dentro un de un arreglo objeto en un archivo JSON externo con php.

Este es mi archivo JSON:

```
[{
 "x": 75,
 "y": 380,
 "width": 320,
 "height": 130,
 "class": "link",
 "data": {
    "proceso": "https://www.google.com",
    "detalle": "hhtps://facebook.com",
    "ultimo": "https://www.youtube.com"
 }

}]
```

Lo que quisiera obtener es el valor de propiedad "proceso". Este es mi PHP:

```
<?php 

$datos = file_get_contents( "regions.json" );

$id= 1;

$objetos = json_decode($datos, true);


foreach ($objetos as $objeto) {
  foreach ($objeto as $celda) {
     if ($id === 1) {
        echo "<a href='".$celda['proceso']."'>hola</a>";
    }else {
        echo "<a href='".$celda['detalle']."'>hola</a>";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Lo que me arroja de resultado: 
`holaholaholahola
Warning: Illegal string offset 'proceso' in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-json\obtener.php on line 13
holahola`

¿Qué ando haciendo mal...?, quiero obtener solo.
     [hola](https://www.google.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer es por que estas tratando de acceder a la propiedad que no existe ya que estas fuera de la posición, prueba solo haciendo un recorrido.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php 
$datos = file_get_contents( "regions.json" );
$id= 1;
$objetos = json_decode($datos, true);

foreach ($objetos as $objeto) {
  echo "<a href='".(($id === 1)?$objeto["data"]["proceso"]:$objeto["data"]["detalle"])."'>hola</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: se ejecuta lo siguinte `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\php-json\obtener.php on line 14
hola`

Comment: creo que solo requiere un solo ciclo

Comment: así es, este código hace lo que quiero, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Hay varias cosas:

1. No necesitas dos bucles `for` porque no hay otro array dentro de `data`.
2. Dado que es un json, puedes dejarlo tal cual, no necesitas convertirlo a array pasando el parámetro opcional `true` en el `json_decode`. Además la notación JSON es más elegante para fines de legibilidad de código
3. Y, puedes simplificar con un ternario.

Apliquemos lo dicho:

```
$datos='
[{
 "x": 75,
 "y": 380,
 "width": 320,
 "height": 130,
 "class": "link",
 "data": {
    "proceso": "https://www.google.com",
    "detalle": "hhtps://facebook.com",
    "ultimo": "https://www.youtube.com"
 }

}]';

$id= 1;

$objetos = json_decode($datos);


foreach ($objetos as $objeto) {
     echo  ($id === 1) ? "<a href='".$objeto->data->proceso."'>hola</a>" : "<a href='".$objeto->data->detalle."'>hola</a>";
}
```

**Salida:**

```
<a href='https://www.google.com'>hola</a>
```

Comment: correcto, de igual manera funciona a la perfección gracias.